# Failed to add widgets dynamically in output screen in .kv file using python

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, widget, kivy-language, grid-layout

I was trying to add the result to a new screen whose content should be dynamic. I tried a few of the trivial ways given in StackOverflow itself but failed to show any content. my code goes as such.

I am entering multiple data, separated by "," without spaces, using text input, and then splitting it which will be stored as a list. The data will be parsed and an equivalent number of labels should be shown on the output screen which I tried but was not successful in execution (line 51-56 in anbs.py).

For example, the input is "I,am,a,good,boy".
The result should be as it will be in the console, i.e. text of each Label should contain an individual item, but nothing goes to the output screen... just a big button that is used to traverse between the screens.

This is my anbs.py file.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.factory import Factory

Window.size = (600, 600)

class HelpWindow(Screen):
    """
    This is a help window. It contains the functionality of all the given boxes
    on the main window.
    """

    def main_window(self):
        sm.current = "main"

class MainWindow(Screen):
    """
    This is the main window that contains the main form.
    This connects the frontend of the app to the backend
    """
    target = ObjectProperty(None)


    def v_popup(self):
        version_popup()
    
    def help(self):
        sm.current = "help"
    
    def output_window(self):
        sm.current = "output"

    def get_results(self):
        #OutputWindow.main(options = options)
        out_window = OutputWindow()
        out_window.main(self.target.text)
        sm.current = "output"
    

class OutputWindow(Screen):
    """
    This is the output window. All the generated results will be seen here.
    """
    res = ObjectProperty(None)
    res_out = ObjectProperty(None)

    def main(self, options):
        options = list(options.split(","))
        for item in options:
            print(item)
            self.res_out.add_widget(Label(text=item))


    def main_window(self):
        sm.current = "main"

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

def version_popup():
    """
    Version Popup Window.
    """
    
    version = "v1.0"
    version_text = "this is "+version+" for this app"
    vpop = Popup(title="Version",
                    content=Label(text=version_text),
                    size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 400))
    
    vpop.open()

### main builder and WindowManager object
kv = Builder.load_file("start.kv")
sm = WindowManager()

### Adding screens to widget
screens = [MainWindow(name="main"), HelpWindow(name="help"), OutputWindow(name="output")]
for screen in screens:
    sm.add_widget(screen)

sm.current = "main"

### main working
class AnbsApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    AnbsApp().run()
```

and my start.kv file looks like this

```
<HelpWindow>
    name:"help"

    Button:
        id:ms
        text:"Main Screen"
        on_release:
            root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
            root.main_window()

<MainWindow>
    name:"main"

    target : target
    
    
    GridLayout:
        cols:1

        GridLayout:
            cols:3
            
            row_force_default: True
            row_default_height: 50
            
            Button:
                id:hp
                text:"Help"
                on_release:
                    root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
                    root.help()
            
            Button:
                id:version
                text: "Version"
                on_release: 
                    root.v_popup()
        
        GridLayout:
            cols:2
            row_force_default: True
            row_default_height: 30

            Label:
                text:"Target *"
            TextInput:
                id:target
                multiline:False
            
            
        GridLayout:
            cols:3
            row_force_default: True
            row_default_height: 50

            Label:
                text:""
            
            Button:
                text:"Submit"
                on_release:
                    root.get_results()
            
            Label:
                text:""


<OutputWindow>
    name:"output"
    
    res_out:res_out

    GridLayout:
        id:res_out
        cols : 1
        
    
    Button:
        id:ms
        text:"Main Screen"
        on_release:
            root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
            root.main_window()
```

I can't really say whats the major point I am missing in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code:

```
def get_results(self):
    #OutputWindow.main(options = options)
    out_window = OutputWindow()
    out_window.main(self.target.text)
    sm.current = "output"
```

is creating a new instance of `OutputWindow` in the line:

```
out_window = OutputWindow()
```

and then calling the `main()` method of that new instance. However, that new instance is not in your GUI, so no effect is observed. To correct that, change the code to use the instance of `OutputWindow` that is in your GUI:

```
def get_results(self):
    out_window = self.manager.get_screen('output')  # get OutputWindow instance
    out_window.main(self.target.text)
    sm.current = "output"
```

You will also need to adjust the size/position of the `Button` in the `OutputWindow`so that it does not completely cover the `GridLayout`.

Comment: I see the mistake I did. The code is working fine now...